# Add functions to a single ExtJS listener

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to add two functions inside the same listener to be able to combine two values ​​of a combo with two fields disabled and to be enabled depending on the value that it chooses. This is the listener that I created:

```
listeners: {
            render: function() {
                var pago = this;
                    pago.onChangeCuentasFn();
                    pago.onChangeFormaPagoFn();
            }
}
```

And these are the functions that the Listener calls:

```
onChangeFormaPagoFn: function(combo, record, index) {
    var iban = Ext.getCmp('clieIban');
    iban.clearInvalid();
    if (record.data.codigo == 4) {
        iban.setDisabled(false);
    } else {
        iban.setDisabled(true);
    }
},

onChangeCuentasFn: function(combo, record, index) {
    var cuenta = Ext.getCmp('clieCuentas');
    cuenta.clearInvalid();
    if (record.data.codigo == 3) {
        cuenta.setDisabled(false);
    } else {
        cuenta.setDisabled(true);
    }
},
```

Do I have to add addListener or play with functions inside the listeners?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. What is the problem with the code you currently have?

Comment: The listeners I created are a combo of a form and this contains a dropdown with 4 forms of payment. Then I have two fields deactivated and if I choose one form of payment it is activated one or the other. In this case they are the form of payment 3 and 4. But when I choose either one only unlocks one. One steps on another. Do you need to see the combo code?

Answer (score 1):

The `Observable` method `addListener` it is cumulative in behavior. That means that if one is calling it twice bth of the handlers will get executed chronologically. 
If
`instance.addListener(eventName, handler1, scope1)`
 AND 
`instance.addListener(eventName, handler2, scope2)` 
When `eventName` is fired 
`handler1` gets executed and then `handler2` gets executed (if handler1 does'n intentionally stope event propagation or returns false).

But declaring listeners in the config zone will not let you call the `addListener` twice. There you could use the implicit call as you did but keep the scope and arguments (which you don't), or combine the handlers with Ext.Function utilities `Ext.Function.createSequence`.

```
var sayHi = function(name){
 alert('Hi, ' + name);
};

sayHi('Fred'); // alerts "Hi, Fred"

var sayGoodbye = Ext.Function.createSequence(sayHi, function(name){
                                                       alert('Bye, ' + name);
                });

sayGoodbye('Fred'); // both alerts show
```

Implicit calling with scope and arguments:

```
listeners: {
        render: function() {
            var me = this;

            if( me.onChangeCuentasFn.apply(me, arguments)!== false ) { // give first hanlder a chance to stop execution if false is returned
              me.onChangeFormaPagoFn.apply(me, arguments);
           }
        }
}
```

The elegant way:

```
initComponent: function () {
  var me = this,
      combindHanlerFn = Ext.Function.createSequence(me.onChangeCuentasFn,me.onChangeFormaPagoFn, me);



  Ext.apply(me, {
    listeners: {
        render:combindHanlerFn 
     }
  });

  return me.callParent(arguments);
);
```